# How to calculate the conditional min-entropy via a semidefinite program?

Tags: information-theory, relative-entropy, min-entropy, semidefinite-programming, cvx

I am trying to formulate the calculation of conditional min-entropy as a semidefinite program. However, so far I have not been able to do so. Different sources formulate it differently. For example, in this highly influential [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1338), it has been formulated as:

$$H_{\text{min}}(A|B)_\rho = - \underset{\sigma_B} {\text{inf}} \ D_{\infty}(\rho_{AB} \| id_A \otimes \sigma_B) 
$$
Where $$\rho_{AB} \in \mathcal{H_A \otimes H_B}, \sigma \in \mathcal{H_B}$$ and
$$D_{\infty}(\tau \| \tau') = \text{inf} \{\lambda \in 
\mathbb{R}: \tau \leq 2^{\lambda} \tau' \}$$

How do I formulate it into a semidefinite program? It is possible as is mentioned in this [lecture](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~vidick/teaching/120_qcrypto/LN_Week3.pdf).

A possible SDP program is given in Watrous's [lecture](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/CS867.Winter2017/Notes/09.pdf):

$$\text{maximize}: <\rho, X>$$
$$\text{subject to}$$
$$Tr_X{X} == \mathcal{1}_Y$$
$$X \in \text{Pos}(X \otimes Y)$$

How do I write it in [CVX](http://cvxr.com/) or any other optimization system?

Comment: What do you want to know? How to write it as an SDP, or how to solve the SDP?

Comment: How could I write it in CVX properly?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an answer. The following should be the CVX code for one of the formulations found in this [link](https://www.slideshare.net/wtyru1989/smooth-entropies-a-tutorial).

```
cvx_begin sdp
variable X(2, 2) hermitian

minimize(trace(id' * X)) % id is eye(2)
subject to

kron(id, X) >= rho_ab % the tensor product of two density matrices a, b
X >= 0

cvx_end
```

The optimal value found in this program is $$\text{optval} = e^{-H_{\text{min}}(A|B)}.$$ So simple calculation would solve for ${H_{\text{min}}(A|B)}$. It turns out to be pretty simple at the end, given that the theoretical foundation leading up to this solution is not quite straightforward.

Comment: The implementation here is not fully correct. You should replace 'variable X(2,2) semidefinite' with 'variable X(2,2) hermitian'. Otherwise you are restricting the variable X to have real-valued entries and you will only get a lower bound on Hmin (and this lower bound can be quite a bit lower than the optimum). For example, you can find CQ states for which the above program would say Hmin(X|E) < 0, which is not possible for a cq-state.